# Form background color only working in IE 8?

Tags: html, css

Normally, IE8 is the bane of my existence, but in this case it's the only browser that seems to be picking up the form background color correctly.  Here is the CSS that seems to only be behaving as expected in IE8.  Both Firefox and Safari have no background color to the forms.

```
#defaultform {

width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
background: #f0f0f0;
overflow:auto;

/* Border style */
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;

/* Border Shadow */
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;

}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example.

Comment: [Works in Chrome...](http://jsfiddle.net/vJQCH/)

Answer (score 0):

Can it be your doctype ? It works for me in Firefox and Safari using this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#defaultform {

width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
background: #f0f0f0;
overflow:auto;

/* Border style */
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;

/* Border Shadow */
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc; 

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="defaultform" name="myform">
    <label>Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```